# function call failed to execute with swapExactETHForTokens on pancakeswap

Tags: solidity, hardhat, pancakeswap, swaps, failed-transaction

My friends, I am trying to create a function to swap WBNB vs tokens On pancakeswap. I can swap token vs token, But when I try to swap WBNB vs token, I'm stuck and get the error in the end of this post. I have lost almost two days with this problem, and need some help.

I am in solidity 0.6.6

I can not find the solution to swap from WBNB. This code is from my pancakeCall() function (wich works fine). I am testing it on hardhat.

```
function placeTrade(address _fromToken,address _toToken,uint256 _amountIn) payable public returns (uint256) {



    address pair = IUniswapV2Factory(PANCAKE_FACTORY).getPair(_fromToken,_toToken);
    
    require(pair != address(0), "Pool does not exist (for trade)");

    // Calculate Amount Out
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = _fromToken;
    path[1] = _toToken;
    uint256 amountRequired = IUniswapV2Router01(PANCAKE_ROUTER).getAmountsOut(_amountIn, path)[1];


    uint256 amountReceived ;

    if (_fromToken == WBNB) {
         //pair is BNB / token');

        amountReceived = IUniswapV2Router02(PANCAKE_ROUTER).swapExactETHForTokens{value: _amountIn}(amountRequired,path,address(this),deadline)[1];    
   
    }
    else{
        //pair is token / token);
        amountReceived = IUniswapV2Router02(PANCAKE_ROUTER).swapExactTokensForTokens(_amountIn,amountRequired,path,address(this),deadline)[1];
        
    }
    require(amountReceived > 0, "Aborted Tx: Trade returned zero");


    return amountReceived;
}
```

with

```
_fromToken = 0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c (WBNB),
_toToken = 0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82 (CAKE),
amountRequired = 124469973506970755485
_amountIn: = 2000000000000000000
```

The swapExactETHForTokens() function returns me this error

```
Error: Transaction reverted: function call failed to execute
at PancakeFlashSwap.placeTrade (contracts/FlashSwap.sol:93)
at PancakeFlashSwap.pancakeCall (contracts/FlashSwap.sol:231)
at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x58f876857a02d6762e0101bb5c46a8c1ed44dc16)
at PancakeFlashSwap.startArbitrage (contracts/FlashSwap.sol:187)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:1805:23)
at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:494:16)
at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:1522:18)
at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:118:18)
at EthersProviderWrapper.send (node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

thanks for your time :)/